# Strange issue using angular 2 bindings together with jade

Tags: html, pug, angular, angular2-template

I have an issue which somewhat makes me unable to combine Angular 2 and jade.

The following jade code

```
input([(test1)]="test1" [(test2)]="test2")
```

translates into

```
<input [(test1)]="test2"/>
```

Does anyone know of a workaround?

**UPDATE**
I found a workaround. But it really is ugly:

```
input&attributes({"[(test1)]": "test1", "[(test2)]": "test2"})
```

I am very interested in a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got help from one of the jade developers on github: https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/2223

There are two options either use quotes around the attributes or separate them with a comma:

```
input("[(test1)]"="test1" "[(test2)]"="test2")
input([(test1)]="test1", [(test2)]="test2")
```

Personally I prefer the latter.